# Please help with this approximation problem

Tags: approximation

Question : If you approximate $2.7145$ to $2.715$ then write the percentage relative error.

A) $0.000106$%

B)$0.00106$%

C) $0.0106$%

D) $0.106$%

I tried this by using the following approach :
$$100 \times\frac {\text{assumed value }- \text{ original value }} {\text{assumed value }}$$
but I did not get any results. Please anyone help me understand how to solve.

Comment: This is two different questions. Please post only one question at a time, and include your own thoughts about the problem. How would you start solving it?

Comment: @MattiP.I am sorry I am new here. This my first post, I don't understand how to edit this. I am sorry I am having trouble understanding the platform. Please don't report or anything. :(

Answer (score 1):

Percent Error =

$ \frac {Vobserved - Vtrue} {Vtrue}
=  
\frac{2.715 - 2.7145}
{2.7145}
=  
\frac {0.00049999999999972} { 2.7145} * 100
=  0.018419598452744 % $